# Drawing Image to Canvas Sometimes Doesn't Display Anything

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I'm trying to learn Canvas and am running into an odd glitch that I can't figure out although I'm sure it is just something stupid I'm overlooking. Basically, I have a page where you can select a local image file. It will then draw it to a canvas that has been resized to fit the image and when you move your mouse over the image it gives the coordinates of the cursor and displays some guide lines.

The page is [here](http://projects.gregoryhanson.com/ImgCoords/index.html).

The issue I'm having is when you select a file it will randomly resize the canvas to 0x0 and from that point forward no matter what image file you select it will remain at that size. If you refresh the page and select the same image file that caused the problem last time then it might work and display properly (or it might not).

I don't think it's a browser cache issue since I've seen it happen where I selected File1 and it worked fine, selected File2 and it worked fine, then selected File1 again and it broke. Also, if I'm understanding it correctly then setting the event handler for the FileReader to onloadend should avoid any issue of it trying to draw the image prior to it being fully read.

Here is my code (I'm sure there are far more concise ways of doing this but I'm still learning). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Image Coordinates Inspector</title>  
    <style>
        body {
            background: #4a4a4a;
            color: #fdcd00;
        }   
        #canvas {
            margin-left: 15px;
            background: #ffffff;
            border: thin inset rgba(100, 150, 230, 0.5);
            cursor: crosshair;
            display: none;
        }
        #coordinates {
            margin-left: 15px;
        }   
        #fileselect {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="imgcoords.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="initializePage()">
    <div id='fileselect'>
        <form>
            <input id="filename" name="filename" type="file" accept="image/*">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id='coordinates'></div>
    <canvas id='canvas'>
        Canvas not supported.
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**imgcoords.js**

```
var canvas,
    coordinates,
    filename,
    context,
    img = new Image(),
    coordevent = false;

function initializePage() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    coordinates = document.getElementById('coordinates');
    filename = document.getElementById('filename');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    filename.onchange = function(e) {
        validateFile();
        e.preventDefault();
    };
}

function validateFile() {
    if (filename.value != '' && filename.files[0].type.match(/image.*/)) {
        var file = filename.files[0],
            reader = new FileReader();

        canvas.style.display = "none";
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;
            resizeCanvas();
            drawImageFile();
        };
    } else {
        canvas.style.display = "none";
        alert("Selected file is not a valid image file.");
    }
}

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
}

function windowToCanvas(canvas, x, y) {
    var bbox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    return { x: (x - bbox.left) * (canvas.width / bbox.width),
             y: (y - bbox.top) * (canvas.height / bbox.height)
    };
}

function clearCanvas() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function drawImageFile() {
    clearCanvas();
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    if (!coordevent) {
        canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
            var loc = windowToCanvas(canvas, e.clientX, e.clientY);

            drawImageFile();
            drawGuidelines(loc.x, loc.y);
            updateCoordinates(loc.x, loc.y);
        };
        coordevent = true;
    }

    updateCoordinates(0, 0);
    canvas.style.display = "inline";
}

function drawGuidelines(x, y) {
    context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 230, 0.8)';
    context.lineWidth = 0.5;
    drawVerticalLine(x);
    drawHorizontalLine(y);
}

function updateCoordinates(x, y) {
    coordinates.innerHTML = '(' + x.toFixed(0) + ', ' + y.toFixed(0) + ')';
}

function drawHorizontalLine(y) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, y + 0.5);
    context.lineTo(context.canvas.width, y + 0.5);
    context.stroke();
}

function drawVerticalLine(x) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x + 0.5, 0);
    context.lineTo(x + 0.5, context.canvas.height);
    context.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW, Nice measuring tool you've got there!

Change this:

```
reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    img.src = e.target.result;
    resizeCanvas();
    drawImageFile();
};
```

To this  --  in order to give img the time it needs to load:

```
reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    img.onload=function(){
        resizeCanvas();
        drawImageFile();
    }
    img.src = e.target.result;
};
```

Also, there is a new Chrome bug that you may want to avoid like this:

```
// img = new Image() is buggy in Chrome
img = document.createElement("img"),
```

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, but it's actually an example from the book _Core HTML5 Canvas_ so I can't take credit for it. I was just trying to switch it so you can select a local file rather than it just using a hard coded image file on the server. :) Anyway, I made your changes and now it works like a champ. Never occurred to me to check for the loading of the actual image as well. Thanks a lot!